# leafletjs default location update with map watch option kCLErrorDomain error 0

Tags: ios, leaflet

I am trying the watch function in leafletjs to update the map and current location.

I also want to use:
        function onLocationFound(e) {
var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

```
                    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
                            .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

            }
```

to have an icon of the current location

I get a kCLErrorDomain error 0

It appears to be related to the mark in leafletjs

Answer (score 0):

I found it!  onLocationFound needs to be under the map.locate. Works like a charm now.

map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16 , watch: true, enableHighAccuracy: true , maximumAge: 5000 , timeout: 10000});
function onLocationFound(e) {

marker1.setLatLng(e.latlng);
}

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);